# How can I insert JSONP data?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I want to write a web widget that allows users to show content of "my mydomain.com" within their web pages.

As far as I can see, this should be possible with jsonp. Unfortunately, I’m not able to find a solution. That's what I did:

1:
On my server on mexample.com I installed a webservice retrieving json data.

http://example.com/wr_rest/views/sponsored.json?&display_id=block_xf&limit=1

This works fine. If I call this url I can see the json within the browser window.

2: On my client at anydomain.com I’ve built a html page widgetpage.html where I would like to insert this json result.

jquery loads here...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com/wr_rest/views/sponsored.json?&display_id=block_xf&limit=1',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
   });

});
```

when I load widgetpage.html I get an cross domain ajax error.

What is my mistake?

Comment: Did you serve up JSONP, and not just JSON ?

Comment: you are right @adeneo I had an error in my posting. The correct url I'm calling ends wit .json. With this I do not get a cross domain error, I can see the resultset returned in firebug, but there is no data written to my console. it seems as if the success: part of the ajax call is not executed...